# Parse variable to URL in PHP (JSON)

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm having an issue to load all the movieID and parse it into the location `$movieID` for `url2`. 
With the code that i am having now (First Code), it will only retrieve one particular movie. When I click on the button, it have an alert box stating if it's success or error. I understand that because `$url2` is outside of the loop. Hence, it's only able to retrieve one particular movie.

On second code, I have place it inside the for loop. However, it will keep looping and when I try to click on the button, it doesn't works. There is no alert box pop up.

How can I make the button works for all the $movieID that parse through the link?

First Code:

```
<?php    
      $url1 = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.movie.com:/retrieveMovies'));
      $counter = count($url1);
       for ($i = 0; $i < $counter; $i++){
        $movieID = $url1[$i]->movieId ;
       }

       $url2 = json_decode(file_get_contents(' http://movie.com/movieOne?seatNum=' . $movieID),TRUE);
       foreach ($url2 as $obj){
           $testingResult = $obj['avail'];
           echo "<button onclick = testBTN('".$testingResult."')>Seat ID</button>";           
       }
        ?>
<script>   
            function testBTN(x) {
             if (x == "OK"){
             alert("Seat booked" );
          }
          else
          {
              alert("Error in booking seats" );
          }

        } 

            </script>
```

second code:

```
<?php    
      $url1 = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://www.movie.com:/retrieveMovies'));
      $counter = count($url1);
       for ($i = 0; $i < $counter; $i++){
        $movieID = $url1[$i]->movieId ;


       $url2 = json_decode(file_get_contents(' http://movie.com/movieOne?seatNum=' . $movieID),TRUE);
       foreach ($url2 as $obj){
           $testingResult = $obj['avail'];
           echo "<button onclick = testBTN('".$testingResult."')>Seat ID</button>";           
       }
       }
        ?>
<script>   
            function testBTN(x) {
             if (x == "OK"){
             alert("Seat booked" );
          }
          else
          {
              alert("Error in booking seats" );
          }

        } 

            </script>
```

Comment: Try this https://pastebin.com/0yrC7n2V

Comment: Warning: Illegal string offset 'avail' , it have this error

Comment: How about this https://pastebin.com/x3jP9kjt

Comment: undefined    $testingResult = $seat['avail'];

Comment: $seat is not being declared